# Remove duplication from this snippet of code

Tags: c#, coding-style, refactoring, duplicates

Looking for advice in removing duplication from this snippet:

```
foreach (Car car in carList) {
    DataRow row = NewRow();

    StringBuilder sbConfigurations = new StringBuilder();    
    foreach (ConfigurationItem configurationItem in car.Configurations)
        sbConfigurations.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", configurationItem.Name, configurationItem.Value);

    row["configurations"] = sbConfigurations;


    StringBuilder sbOptionals = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (OptionalItem optionalItem in car.Optionals) 
        sbOptionals.AppendFormat("{0}, ", optionalItem.Name);

    row["optionals"] = sbOptionals;

    Rows.Add(row);
}
```

EDIT: This is a simplified context, there could be more list-joins like these

Comment: I was thinking of something using an array with the names of the indices, but then I saw that you are calling `car.Optionals`. You could do this by using reflection, but that wouldn't make it better.

Comment: Do Configurations and Optionals derive from a common base class? If not, then significant simplification will probably involve reflection. If you're going to be doing this a lot, you could maybe justify the effort to write a function like obj.FormattedOutput(" {Name}: {Value}\n")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree there isn't much duplication, but maybe this 'literal translation' into Linq Extensions 
is what you are looking for (type in-browser, so not tested - yet):

```
foreach (Car car in carList) {
    DataRow row = NewRow();

    row["configurations"] = car.Configurations.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a,i) => a.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", i.Name, i.Value));
    row["optionals"] = car.Optionals.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a,i) => a.AppendFormat("{0}, ", i.Name));

    Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write it somewhat more legible(/efficient?) without stringbuilders:

Extracting the lambda made the lines shorter:

```
Func<Car, string> nameValue = car => string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", car.Name, car.Value);

foreach (var car in carList) {
    var row = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    row["configurations"] = string.Join("\n", car.Configurations.Select(nameValue));
    row["optionals"]      = string.Join(", ", car.Optionals.Select(i => i.Name));

    list.Add(row);
}
```

<sub>**Note** Before C# 4.0 you need additional `.ToArray()` calls on the second parameter to `string.Join`</sub>

Comment: just learned a new c# feature :P, although I think there is too much function calls in the same line, im looking also for clean code.

Comment: Hehe. Did improve it a little bit more - addressing the 'long lines' complaint.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think removing what you are referring to as "duplication" is necessary.  You don't have two occurrences of identical code, but two occurrences of similar code.  This is common and nothing to be concerned with.

Comment: Thats a point, but still I think I could implement something to abstract the insertion os lists inside a row column.

Comment: @arkilus  : yep you can but I;'m not sure whether it make sense in such a simpe case, will post a solution in a minute

Comment: In my example there is only 1 "repetition", what if I got to add more columns like these?

Answer (score 2):

How about turning the problem upside-down. Instead of making the function understand `DataRow` format for each object, have each object understand `DataRow` format. If you aren't using `object.ToString()` for anything, you can make `ConfigurationItem` and `OptionalItem` implement `object.ToString()`:

```
class ConfigurationItem
{
    public string override ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", Name, Value);
    }
}

class OptionalItem
{
    public string override ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, ", Name);
    }
}
```

Now you can use a single loop for all types of objects:

```
string BuildDataRowString(IEnumerable collection)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var o in collection) sb.Append(o.ToString());
    return sb.ToString();
}

row["configurations"] = car.Configurations.BuildDataRowString();
row["optionals"] = car.Optionals.BuildDataRowString();
```

If you need `object.ToString()` for other purposes, you can add a custom format for "`DataRow` format":

```
class ConfigurationItem : IFormattable
{
    public string override ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (format == "D") {
            return string.Format(formatProvider, "{0}: {1}\n", Name, Value);
        }
        return this.ToString(); // otherwise format as default
    }
}

class OptionalItem : IFormattable
{
    public string override ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (format == "D") {
            return string.Format(formatProvider, "{0}, ", Name);
        }
        return this.ToString(); // otherwise format as default
    }
}

string BuildDataRowString(this IEnumerable e, string format)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var o in e) sb.AppendFormat("{0:D}", o);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```